# Entering value greater than Range Domain maximum?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, file-geodatabase, domains

I created a range domain in a file geodatabase. The type is short integer and ranges from 0 to 200. The domain was assigned to a new column I created. But I could still enter a value greater than 200 to the column of the newed feature (point).

Just unsure what I did wrong.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A feature/flaw of range domains is that you can enter a value which is outside of the range. The error is only flagged if you choose [Validate Features](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t000000mp000000.htm) on the Editor toolbar

Comment: Then if I expose the feature class to ArcGIS Online as a feature service and editing of feature is allowed, is "validation features" gonna work?

Comment: Great question - I'm not sure the answer. Can you post this as a new question with something like "how are range domains validated when editing a feature service online?" and tag it as ArcGIS Server / ArcGIS Online?

Comment: Thanks! I've made a new question here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109532/how-are-range-domains-validated-when-editing-a-feature-service-in-arcgis-online