# Validating range domains when editing feature service in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, domains

I have a feature class and a range domain is applied to a field. I know we can use the "Validate Features" command for validation.

When the feature class is published to ArcGIS Online and exposed as a feature service, how is validation applied? Is it automatic?

Comment: This is a good question. The [help file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0154000003nt000000) mentions coded-value domains in this context ("For example, if you have a domain limiting the color of a fire hydrant to red, yellow, or blue, you see a drop-down list in the web application that allows you to only select one of those three colors"), but doesn't mention range domains

Comment: Not really an answer, but given that your other post mentions thousands of valid values in the domain, a suggestion is to move the validation out of ArcGIS and handle it yourself in JavaScript

Comment: Does your testing indicate that validation is applied at all?